# http.Get returning error 429 too many requests after one use when the webpage works fine in my browser

Tags: http, go

I am trying to save web pages in Go through the http.Get function. However, even after running the function below once I am getting a too many request error. I can enter this URL in my browser and it will work fine, even if I refresh a few times. Is there any fix/ reason for this?

```
func query(URL string) {
  page, err := http.Get("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + URL + "/.json")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  responseData, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(page.Body)
  fmt.Println(string(responseData))
}
```

Comment: Oh okay. How would i change the header value/ user agent to something more suitable?

Comment: Many thanks. It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned, you can bypass this by setting a user agent:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   s := "http://reddit.com/r/videos/comments/m9zcp8.json"
   req, e := http.NewRequest("HEAD", s, nil)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
   res, e := new(http.Client).Do(req)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer res.Body.Close()
   println(res.StatusCode == 200)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Request.Header

Answer (score 2):

Websites will use a variety of tools including header flagging to determine the legitimacy of requests. I'd suggest adding the respective headers your browser sets on connecting to Reddit.

```
    req.Header.Set("authority", "www.reddit.com")
    req.Header.Set("pragma", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("cache-control", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("sec-ch-ua", `"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"`)
    req.Header.Set("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0")
    req.Header.Set("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
    req.Header.Set("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36")
    req.Header.Set("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
    req.Header.Set("dnt", "1")
    req.Header.Set("sec-fetch-site", "none")
    req.Header.Set("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate")
    req.Header.Set("sec-fetch-user", "?1")
    req.Header.Set("sec-fetch-dest", "document")
    req.Header.Set("accept-language", "en-GB,en;q=0.9")
```